# Spring Boot + PostgreSQL: cannot find schema to create Camunda tables

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, camunda

I am trying to create tables for camunda (7.14.0) at Spring Boot application start. I have manually created a PostgreSQL schema in advance with the name "camunda". When I run the Spring Boot application, it gives me an error:

```
ENGINE-03017 Could not perform operation 'create' on database schema for SQL Statement ...
```

and

```
org.postgresql.util.psqlexception: no schema has been selected to create in
```

My application.yml config:

```
camunda:
  bpm:
    database:
      type: postgres
      schema-update: create
      schema-name: camunda
      username: camunda
      password: camunda
      table-prefix: camunda.
```

How can I create camunda tables in a schema with a specific name?

Answer (score 2):

Example config:

```
spring.datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?autoReconnect=true
  username: cam1
  password: cam1
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
camunda:
  bpm:
    database:
      schema-name: cam1
      table-prefix: cam1.
```

Ensure the schema has been created and user used has been given the **permissions** on the target schema.
Full example for two Camunda instances using separate schemas: https://github.com/rob2universe/two-camunda-instances